# JSON Handling in Python and Online JSON Linters

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Consider the string

```
{"Key":"Value\nNewLine"}
```

Online json linters consider this string as valid string and parse it

but the Python code:

```
json_str ='''{"Key":"Value\nNewLine"}'''
dict = json.loads(json_str)
```

Fails. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `\n` is a newline, not a backslash and an n.  You want:

```
json_str = r'''{"Key":"Value\nNewLine"}'''
```

Comment: So the important thing is: OP should use **raw string** or ``json_str = '''{"Key":"Value\\nNewLine"}'''``